# Sending input to the computer programatically

Tags: java, php

This is just for fun.

I'm playing a game where you type A-z as fast as you can, I can't do it faster than in 5 seconds and I think it may be humanly impossible to do it in 1-2 seconds. However, it may be possible to create a small program in Java or Php which, when started, sends the inputs of letter keys A-z to the computer as fast as possible.

How can this be done in either Java or php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise this isn't a solution in the programming languages you want, but for other searchers the open source software [AutoKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is perfect for this kind of thing - automating key presses/mouse movements to perform repetitive tasks.

Comment: actually it turned out to be perfect for me too :p. i typed a-z in 0.44 seconds, lol

Answer (score 2):

If the target game is in Java, you could use the Robot class to send keystrokes to the application. Other than that, there are platform dependent ways to send keystrokes to a different application. On windows, you can use the SendMessage() command with WM_KEY to emulate keystrokes (through JNA for example).